# Can S3 default end-point direct to HTTPS without custom domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

[image][image]We are doing a POC and hosting our site on S3 website, so far so good. By default it exposed HTTP end point, is it possible to convert it to HTTPS without having to use custom domain? We are happy to use the same domain which S3 provides by default just pointing it to HTTPS.

I tried using cloud-front distribution and tried with both bucket name as well as static endpoint in 'Origin Domain Name' but no luck so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a CloudFront Distribution it should work. 
CF will expose an HTTPS endpoint for you, just make sure that

- Under **SSL Certificate** you have selected Default CloudFront Certificate (*.cloudfront.net)
- CF has access to bucket's content. This can be achieved either by making items public in bucket, or, the better option: Allow CF to create an **Origin Access Identity** for you and attach the necessary permissions to the bucket.

[image]

Comment: Could you post what's the error for HTTPS and a print screen of CF Distribution settings?

Comment: Here you go, just updated the ticket with configuration. HTTP requests work fine but HTTPS timeout

Comment: I was able to access it. Saw a login form, entered wrong credentials and ended up with a loading. The CF Distribution seems to be working

Comment: Can you please advise which URL you are accessing? Still no luck with HTTPS, just tried it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211090/discussion-between-radu-di-and-abdul-rehaman).